# fragment crushes when it comes to convert text box data into string

Tags: java, tostring

so when ever i fill up my text boxes and hit add my app comes crushing down , when its in debug mode it highlights in the

```
    String passwd = passowd.getText().toString() ;
```

but here is the oncreateview method

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loging_fragment , container , false );

    return rootview;
     name = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
     passowd = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtpaswd);
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    btnlogin = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              HashMap<String, String>user = session.getUserDetails();                   
                String uname = user.get(session.KEY_NAME);
                String psswd = user.get(session.KEY_PASSWORD);
                String usernam = name.getText().toString();
                String passwd = passowd.getText().toString() ;
                    if ( usernam == uname | passwd == psswd) 
                    {                   
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);       
                        }
                            else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter username and password ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                           

                                }
        }
    });
}
```

now i do not know what goes wrong down there plus am real new in android....

Comment: Please append the exception/stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from `onCreateView` at the second statement, so no code bellow that return statement will be executed. And you should retrieve our views from `viewRoot` instead from `getActivity` You should do:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loging_fragment , container , false );

     name = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
     passowd = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.txtpaswd);
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    btnlogin = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              HashMap<String, String>user = session.getUserDetails();                   
                String uname = user.get(session.KEY_NAME);
                String psswd = user.get(session.KEY_PASSWORD);
                String usernam = name.getText().toString();
                String passwd = passowd.getText().toString() ;
                    if ( usernam == uname | passwd == psswd) 
                    {                   
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);       
                        }
                            else {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Enter username and password ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                           

                                }
        }
    });

    return rootview;
}
```

Comment: now when it reaches at the string usernam = name.getText().tostring(); it crushes saying a null value something , something

Comment: Do you have all that views declared in `ayout.loging_fragment.xml`?

Comment: yeah  i have @algui91

Comment: Paste your logcat please